# Why unit tests should not use database?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, theory

Reading an article [Evil Unit testing](http://www.javaranch.com/unit-testing.jsp), I am not exactly sure WHY the unit tests should never use DB, network or file systems. What if it an network app?

Comment: Not that I disagree with the answers, but was just wondering. Are you looking for a way to test your database? Because there's nothing wrong with that. We are just not allowed to refer to them as 'unit-tests' but we should call them integration tests. Plenty of best practices how to do this. If this was 'just the question you wanted to ask' then ignore this comment :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Unit tests are used to test the functionality of the smallest unit of your code. They should not have any dependency on any external resource that might change in future.

To take an example, let's say today you write a unit test that test a method that performs addition of two numbers.

```
public void AddNumberTest()
{
    int a = 4; // Assume 4 coming from a database.
    int b = 5; // Assume 5 coming from a database.

    int c = a + b;
    Assert.True(9, c);
}
```

This will run today. That's totally cool.

Let's say tomorrow you come and change the functionality of the Add method.
Now you should be able to run the test and it should be pass. But let's assume somehow the database server (or external resource ) is down. Then the test fail.

Even if someone changes the values in database, you need to be aware of the change to be made to the test.

**Is that what you want???  Absolutely not. Right**

That's why we write unit test cases that should be independent of external resources. That where we use mocks and stubs.

**You should be able to run unit test a thousand times and it should give the same results always.**

Comment: You are correct. The point of a unit test is to control the inputs so that you can verify the outputs. If you were to include the database in the test then you would have to manually change the data to known values in the database, meaning you would have to back up the existing data first and then restore it afterwards. This is of course, ridiculous because it adds failure points in your overall system stability, and also it pushes your test out of the scope of a unit test by no longer testing the smallest unit of code.

Comment: i can not fully agree with you.
In my case i unit against sandbox of billing company API and i FOR SURE want to know that everything is fine when deployed other time.

Comment: @ValentinRusk in which case that's an integration test - not a unit test.

Comment: I can understand your point @Dinesh, but if i testing some ORM model class in a back-end application how can I test it without database access? if I use a temporary test database with mock data inside I can consider my test as Unittest instead of integration test?

Comment: I think it best to test them using in memory repository instead of relying on a test database. Using a temp data is again sort of integration test. Some day that database may go down or even if it local may run into permission issues or something else. Some ORM that i worked back ni past provides support for unit testing where we can create mock repository to test our ORM model.

Comment: The real indented question is "how can we test data retrieval from DB without connecting to DB as suggested by some", not testing the operation on the retrieved data.  Mocking it would not cut it.

Answer (score 5):

Unit testing is not intended to test the complete functionality of an application. It is meant to make sure that definable modules of code work as expected. To test an application it is not enough to use unit tests. You must also perform functional testing and regression testing. Database access falls outside the scope of unit testing, so you would not write unit tests that include database access. You would include database access testing in your functional tests. Similarly, if you have a network app, you would not include network access in your unit tests. In both cases you would unit test the code that manipulates the data that it gets from the db or the network using simulated-known data and leave the actual access out of it.

To reiterate, it is not enough to just unit test an app.